# How to use multi lingual mailer templates in the node.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, nodemailer, email-templates

I'm using node email templates in my project for sending out automatic emailers to users on some user events.

> https://github.com/niftylettuce/node-email-templates
>
> https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer

On following the examples mentioned in the github page, I'm able to send the mailer using nodemailer but my problem is how can I support multiple languages in those emailers.

One possible solution can be to have a separate directory of html and style.css but that way there will be too many directories which is not really a good programtic approach.

Can anyone please suggest any better way to achieve this in express ? Is there some existing tool for this ?

https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate

> P.S.: I have successfully handled translations in the angular UI using
>   angular translate. How can I do same in express mailer templates in
>   backend ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any good solution to this?

Comment: @Aides Not yet. Currently I'm supporting only English language in my application.

Answer (score 0):

While this answer uses some very specific technologies it might send you on the right track:

Setup:
`i18n`, `jade`

```
var jade = require('jade');
var i18n = require('i18n');

// [optional] cache read and compiled jade file
var templates = {}

function renderMailWithI18n (templatePath, lang) {
  // use cached and compiled template or load and compile from file
  templates[templatePath] = templates[templatePath] || 
     jade.compileFile(path.join(__dirname, templatePath + '.jade'), { pretty: true});

  // render template and pass i18n translate function
  return templates[templatePath]({
    __: function (translationId) {
      return i18n.__({
        phrase: translationId, locale: lang
      });
    }
  })
}
```

---

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var mailTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport(...);
mailTransporter.sendMail({
  from: ...,
  to: ...,
  subject: i18n.__({ phrase: 'myMail.subject', locale: req.locale }),
  renderMailWithI18n('myMail_text', req.locale).replace('<div>', '').replace('</div>', ''),
  renderMailWithI18n('myMail_html', req.locale)
})
```

---

myMail_text.jade

```
div.
    #{__('myMail.greeting')}

    #{__('myMail.body')}
    ...
```

myMail_html.jade

```
span #{__('myMail.greeting')}
br
span #{__('myMail.body')}
...
```

---

translation_en.json (similar to angular-translate)

```
{
  "myMail": {
    "subject": "English Subject",
    "greeting": "English Greeting",
    "body": English Body"
  }
}
```

---

Additionally don't forget to configure `i18n` to use the correct translation files.